# Ubuntu does not load its local (near) mirror for downloading packaging

Tags: ubuntu, mirror

The Ubuntu server is in Australia. However, every time I perform apt-get install/update/upgrade, it always load the U.S mirror for downloading.

```
$ sudo apt-get install make

...
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  make
...
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main make amd64 3.81-8.1ubuntu1 [118 kB]
Fetched 118 kB in 2s (47.7 kB/s)
```

Which results slow download, ideally, it should get file from **au.archive.ubuntu.com**

Do I misconfig somewhere?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` accordingly and update the database with `apt-get update`.

Answer (score 1):

After installing Ubuntu from an .iso source the installation process can configure:

> 'Software & Update', 'Ubuntu Software', **Downloadable from the internet**, Download from: Server from Australia

Currently (as at July 2021) there is a problem with the Australian mirror and users can experience errors such as 403 Forbidden plus an IP Address. The solution is to select:

> Download from: Main Server

If there were additional installation delays due to use of Main Server then it is unavoidable.

Comment: Thats a normal behavior, they will lead you to a other source in case of issues